# SMPS power supply shows strange AC voltage output

Tags: rf, switch-mode-power-supply, ground-loop

Hi I have been using a simple laptop power adapter (15V) for my electronic
lab-works. And today I'm troubleshooting some RF circuits, and I found a little guilt
about ground loops, So I check everything using a analog AC voltmeter, Finally
I realized that I got 35V AC voltage across power supply lines (output from power
adapter).

What on earth this could be happen? Any idea?
Why this happen ? Should I ignore this?

Comment: Found a little *guilt*?

Comment: You should always wait a while before accepting an answer, to encourage others to contribute solutions. Posting and accepting within an hour doesn't help bring attention to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMPS power supplies are known for not operating well without a load. Your analog AC voltmeter is barely any load at all, and many power supplies when there is no load are not regulated. This will likely explain why the open circuit voltage is 35V. Try adding a resistor that will pull some significant current to see whether the voltage does show as 15V.

Comment: 35V is not DC,but it's AC.

Comment: The SMPS can be oscillating due to the fact that there's no load. It's another surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Such power adapter is not suitable for electronics lab-work. What you're observing is most likely because of capacitor coupling primary and secondary sides to meet EMI requirements. That is so common and so ugly from engineering point of view.